# SPARQL bind predicate/sub-property not variable

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, fuseki

I want to bind property not any variable in sparql.
according to http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind
I can bind any variable like `BIND ( 42 AS ?price )` 
My question is can we define something like this

`BIND ( ?product rdf:price 42 )`
or 
`BIND ( ?product rdf:price ?price )`

OR ideal case for me is 
`BIND ( ?product ?property ?price ) // where ?property can be minPrice, maxPrice or avgPrice`

My use-case is to get this form of information.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
   ?product :title ?title; :brand ?brand; :id ?productID.
   ?product :totalOffers =(assign) {
        select COUNT(?oid) WHERE {?oid :isOfferOf ?productID}
   } 
  // or like this 
  ?product (:totalOffers :minPrice :maxPrice ) =(assign) {
        select COUNT(?oid) MIN(?price) MAX(?price) WHERE {?oid :isOfferOf ?productID. ?oid :price ?price }
   }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that SPARQL execution is bottom up so sub-queries will be evaluated first.  Therefore if you want to assign some values for use in a sub-query then you need to do so inside your sub-query.

To assign multiple variables you can either use several `BIND` statements e.g.

```
BIND("foo" AS ?a)
BIND("bar" AS ?b)
# etc
```

Or you can use a single `VALUES` statement e.g.

```
VALUES ( ?a ?b ) { ( "foo" "bar" ) }
```

So you then just need to use this within your query e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
  {
    SELECT 
      ?product 
      (COUNT(?oid) AS ?offers) 
      (MIN(?price) AS ?minPrice) 
      (MAX(?price) AS ?maxPrice)
    WHERE
    {
      VALUES ( ?product ) 
      { 
        ( <http://example.org/product> ) 
      }
      ?product :id ?productID .
      ?oid :isOfferOf ?productID .
      ?oid :price ?price .
    }
    GROUP BY ?product
  }
  ?product :title ?title ;
           :brand ?brand .
}
```